# multiple row insert inserts 2 extra rows with 0

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

guys im having issue inserting multiple rows all is ok but 3 extra rows with 0 value gets inserted into employee_id

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'][$i];
    $employee_name = $_POST['employee_name'][$i];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'][$i];
    $time_in = $_POST['time_in'][$i];
    $time_out = $_POST['time_out'][$i];
    $team = $_POST['team'][$i];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendance (employee_id, employee_name, remarks, time_in, time_out, team) VALUES ('$user_id', '$employee_name', '$remarks','$time_in', '$time_out', '$team')"); 
$i++;
} 
}
```

and this is the form

```
$time_in = date('Y-m-d H:i');
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE login != 'admin'");
            $rowNo = 1; //Increment Row Number
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $id = $row['member_id'];    
                $user = $row['login'];
                $team = $row['team'];
                echo "<tr align='left'>";   
                echo"<td width='10px'><font color='white'>" .$rowNo++."</font>.</td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'><input type='hidden' name='user_id[]' value='".$id."'/> <input type='hidden' name='employee_name[]' value='".$user."'/> " .$row['login']."</font></td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'>
                <select name='remarks[]'>
                <option valur='Present'>Present</option>
                <option valur='Absent'>Absent</option>
                <option valur='Half Day'>Half Day</option>
                </select>
                </font>
                </td>";
                echo"<td><font color='black'><input type='text' name='time_in[]' value='".$time_in."'/> <input type='text' name='time_out[]' value='".$time_out."'/> <input type='hidden' name='team[]' value='".$team."'/></font></td>";
                echo"<td>";
                echo "<p align='right'>


 </p></tr>";

            }
```

how could this be corrected?

thanks

Comment: What is inside your $_POST?

Comment: Please post the output from `var_dump($_POST)` Your loop iterates over all keys in `$_POST`,  but probably you intend to iterate over just one multi-value key

Comment: Something along the lines of `foreach ($_POST['user_id'] as $val)` assuming `user_id` is always populated.

Comment: i have posted my form now please have a look

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks that helped :) cheers mate

Comment: @tadman this is my offline work just for home purpose else i do use pdo now on rest of my work

Comment: No excuse to not use PDO here. It's easier than bashing around with `mysql_query` and you'll gain more experience doing it properly than in the way it was done in the 1990s. Kill off these bad habits!

Comment: agree mate but its old project way too much to convery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your form look like?

Also, you shouldn't be using mysql_ commands. Deprecated. Should be using mysqli procedural or object-oriented.

Editing to provide likely answer...

Instead of looping over $_POST, name one of your form inputs `form_value[]` or similar and instead loop: `foreach($_POST['form_value'] as $val)`.

Comment: yes i know but this its deprecated but its my old script i have to continue with this way too much work to convert all to pdo

Comment: it should be a comment . not an answer